# Box<X> vs move semantics on X

Tags: rust

I have an easy question regarding `Box<X>`. 
I understand what it does, it allocates `X` on the heap.
In C++ you use the **new** operator to allocate something on the heap so it can outlive the current scope (because if you create something on the stack it goes away at the end of the current block).

But reading Rust's documentation, it **looks** like you can create something on the stack and still return it taking advantage of the language's move semantics without having to resort to the heap.
Then it's not clear to me when to use `Box<X>` as opposed to simply `X`.

I just started reading about Rust so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First of all:** C++11 (and newer) has move semantics with rvalue references, too. So your question would also apply to C++. Keep in mind though, that C++'s move semantics are -- unlike Rust's ones -- highly unsafe.

**Second:** the word "move semantic" somehow hints the absence of a "copy", which is not true. Suppose you have a `struct` with 100 64-bit integers. If you would transfer an object of this struct via move semantics, those 100 integers will be copied (of course, the compiler's optimizer can often remove those copies, but anyway...). The advantage of move semantics comes to play when dealing with objects that deal with some kind of data on the heap (or pointers in general).

For example, take a look at `Vec` (similar to C++'s `vector`): the type itself only contains a pointer and two pointer-sized integer (`ptr`, `len` and `cap`). Those three times 64bit are still copied when the vector is moved, but the main data of the vector (which lives on the heap) is not touched.

---

That being said, let's discuss the main question: "**Why to use `Box` at all?**". There are actually many use cases:

- *Unsized types*: some types (e.g. Trait-objects which also includes closures) are unsized, meaning their size is not known to the compiler. But the compiler has to know the size of each stack frame -- hence those unsized types cannot live on the stack.
- *Recursive data structures*: think of a `BinaryTreeNode` struct. It saves two members named "left" and "right" of type... `BinaryTreeNode`? That won't work. So you can box both children so that the compiler knows the size of your struct.
- *Huge structs*: think of the 100 integer struct mentioned above. If you don't want to copy it every time, you can allocate it on the heap (this happens pretty seldom).

Comment: What makes C++ moves particularly unsafe?

Comment: While in Rust, the compiler guarantees that the programmer can't access an object that has been moved, C++ allows using the moved object. In particularly bad cases you could access pointers to freed memory or other invalid data.

Comment: This is not more unsafe than anything else in C++. Eg. in C++ a copy constructor might copy a raw pointer and then you’d get a double-free. C++ just expects you to implement a well-behaved {copy,move} constructor here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to say that C++ moves are unsaf*er* than everything else in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand C++11/14 move semantics but C++ is a language I'm confortable with. With Rust I'm just starting to get my feet wet and I want to know whats going on behind the curtains.
You are right, I was assuming Rust was (magically) avoiding a copy altogether when move semantics were used on a non-Copy type.

Comment: Regarding the recursive data structure, what's wrong with storing two references/pointers to BinaryTreeNode instead of boxing them?

Comment: @royalstream Well... who would be responsible for freeing it then? A `Box` is just a pointer, that frees the memory when it goes out of scope. Of course you could pre-allocate all tree-nodes somewhere else and take care of deallocation is some special way. But it's easiest to say that the parent node owns it's children and hence is responsible for freeing them.

Comment: If you were using references who would own the nodes? As for raw pointers they are avoided in Rust because unsafe.

Comment: I was thinking of references using a lifetime parameter (like I've seen in several examples). But you're right, that will imply someone else owns them which is unnatural for such a structure. Thanks again.

Comment: @royalstream Since null references are not valid in Rust, they would have to reference actual instances of BinaryTreeNode (in this example).  That would put us back to infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

There are cases where you can’t return `X` eg. if `X` is `?Sized` (traits, non-compile-time-sized arrays, etc.). In those cases `Box<X>` will still work.