# Is it possible to transfer ownership other than by using a move or Box?

Tags: rust

The Rust Book mainly talks about move mechanics, but if I have a large structure I see that the Rust compiler produces code that copies the contents of the structure when I pass it by value to a function:

```
struct S2 {
    a: u64,
    b: u64,
    c: u64,
    d: u64,
    e: u64,
    f: u64,
    g: u64,
    h: u64,
    i: u64,
}

struct S {
    a: u64,
    b: u64,
    c: u64,
    d: u64,
    e: u64,
    f: u64,
    g: u64,
    h: u64,
    i: u64,
    s: S2,
}

fn xxx(xs: S) {
    println!("{:p}", &xs.s.a);
}

fn main() {
    let ms = S {
        a: 1,
        b: 1,
        c: 1,
        d: 1,
        e: 1,
        f: 1,
        g: 1,
        h: 1,
        i: 1,
        s: S2 {
            a: 1,
            b: 1,
            c: 1,
            d: 1,
            e: 1,
            f: 1,
            g: 1,
            h: 1,
            i: 1,
        },
    };
    println!("{:p}", &ms.s.a);
    xxx(ms);
}
```

In the output, I see that Rust didn't optimize the move of `ms` to the function parameter `xs` to use a pointer, but rather copied the entire thing. I used `opt-level=3`:

```
$ ./test
0x7ffeea23a8a8
0x7ffeea23a818
```

Is this something I should worry about? Is it recommended to use `Box` for large structs?

Comment: Also relevant: [Box<X> vs move semantics on X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125998/boxx-vs-move-semantics-on-x).